# Going from max of set to l.u.b. of a set in proving a metric

Tags: general-topology

We have to verify the metric $d(f,g)=l.u.b\:\cup_{x\in [a,b]}\{|f(x)-g(x)|\}$ for f,g continuous satisfies the Schwartz inequality (triangle inequality). It is easy to prove that if F and G are functions of a discrete variable $d(F,G)=max\: \cup_x\{|f(x)-g(x)|\}$ satisfies the inequality, but I stumble on the corresponding proof for functions of a continuous variable using least upper bound.

Comment: What does the union symbol represent in you formula?  Is $[a,b]$ taken from a larger subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It is all points in the closed interval from a to b on the real line.

Comment: You can just pick another function $h(x)$, and show that $d(f,g) \leq d(f,h)+d(h,g)$.  You should find that the triangle inequality in $d(f,g)$ is inherited from the triangle inequality for absolute value.  Remember that the triangle inequality for absolute value holds regardless of whether x is discrete.  Hope this helps a little.

Comment: @D.B Sorry, it does not. The difficulty is going from a statement about "max" to a statement about l.u.b